# Unable to pass argument to subprocess with POpen

Tags: python, arguments, subprocess, popen, ros

I'm currently looking into creating a general configuration tool for ROS (Robot Operating System). Using `subprocess.POpen()` and `Tkinter` I'm creating a `treeview` like this:

[image]

The first two columns are rather simple to create due to the neat way `rospack list` (a command that lists all packages that are installed on the system including the ones that are inside the respective workspace where the developer creates his own packages) works:

```
ros_packages_install_retrieve = subprocess.Popen(["rospack list"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ros_packages_installed = []
for ros_package in ros_packages_install_retrieve.stdout.readlines():
    ros_package_adapted = ros_package.split(" ")
    ros_package_adapted[1] = ros_package_adapted[1][:-1]
    ros_packages_installed.append(ros_package_adapted)
```

The **Requires** column is the tricky one due to a problem with calling `rospack depends <package>` (lists (if any) all packages the `<package>` requires to be present on the system in order to build and/or run). For each package that is inside `ros_packages_installed` I call the following function:

```
def get_deps(ros_package):
    ros_package_deps_retrieve = subprocess.Popen(["rospack", "depends", ros_package], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ros_package_deps = []
    for ros_package_dep in ros_package_deps_retrieve.stdout.readlines():
        ros_package_dep = ros_package_dep.split("\n")
        ros_package_dep = ros_package_dep[:-1]
        ros_package_deps.append(ros_package_dep)

    return ros_package_deps
```

The problem is that I'm getting

> [rospack] Error: no package given

and the return value is always an empty list. I even tried concatenating the `ros_package` argument to the command itself but all in vain.

During my futile attempts I found something rather strange. Both `list` and `depends` are actually arguments that are passed to `rospack`. In fact if you call `rospack` only you will get an error telling you to call `rospack help` to see the available arguments.

Therefore I tried splitting these things up and passed `["rospack", "list"]` and `["rospack", "depends", "ros_package"]` to the two `POpen` calls. For my surprise I got

> [rospack] Error: no command given. Try 'rospack help' [rospack]
>
> [rospack] Error: no command given.  Try 'rospack help'

which at least for me is a rather strange behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a confusion with how to run Popen. You should either pass a single string with `shell=True`:

```
 ros_package_deps_retrieve = subprocess.Popen("rospack depends %s"rospack, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or pass it as a completely separate list, and use `shell=False` (the default, not necessary to specify):

```
 ros_package_deps_retrieve = subprocess.Popen(["rospack", "depends", rospack], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

See the documentation here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Important pieces (below are relevant quotes from the docs):

> If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather
>   than as a sequence. ...
>
> If args is a sequence, the first item
>   specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated
>   as additional arguments to the shell itself.

So when you pass `shell=True` and pass it like `['rospack', 'list']`, `rospack` ends up being the command, and `list` becomes an argument to the *shell*, not what you wanted.

When `shell=False` and you pass it like `['rospack depends', rosmodule]`, that makes the string `'rospack depends'` the command to run, which doesn't exist and therefore fails.